# Plot confidence interval for regression with clustered standard error in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a regression model with confidence interval in `ggplot`. In my model I want to use robust standard errors clustered on a variable. However, I can't find where I can locate the variable for clustering errors.

I have already tried `geom_smooth` function with `lm_robust` method but can't find where to add cluster error variable.

```
p1 +geom_smooth(data=data,aes(y=y,x=x),method='lm_robust',se = T)
```

I need the equilavent for the following line in `ggplot` for the plot:

```
lm_robust(y~ x, data = data, clusters = z)
```

Comment: Add `method.args = list(clusters = z)`?

Comment: I added `method.args=list(clusters=z)` and returned the following error: "object "z" not found" then tried `method.args=list(clusters="z")` and got this error "Computation failed in stat_smooth():
variable lengths differ (found for (cluster))"

Comment: I don't know what package `lm_robust` comes from, so I'm not sure how one normally uses the `clusters` argument, and I can't try it out.

Comment: it comes from `estimatr` package. and here an example of manually used clusters from its documents: `lmclust <- lm_robust(y ~ x + z, data = dat, clusters = clusterID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the non-standard evaluation gives problems, but you can instead just pass the whole data.frame column like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(estimatr)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, qsec)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm_robust', method.args = list(cluster = mtcars$cyl))
```

Note that this will give not work when drawing multiple lines (e.g. using color) or with facets.

Comment: Thanks but get the following error running exact code when running the exact code 
 "Error in geom_smooth(method = "lm_robust", method.args = list(cluster = cyl)) : 
  object 'cyl' not found"