# Adding clustered standard errors to trend line in scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-error

I want to show the difference in price trend for two types of observations, one treated and one control group. For this, I created a simple graph:

```
linearity_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = price_per_meter, color = as.factor(treatment))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess') +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Price Per Meter vs Year by Treatment",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Price Per Meter") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Treatment", labels = c("Control", "Treated"))
```

I am also performing some other econometrics (namely a DiD) and for this I have needed to cluster the standard errors on a municipal level (`mun_code`). However, it seems I cannot make the confidence bounds on my graph also use these clustered SE, and as such, they are way too narrow.

I have tried following [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299003/plot-confidence-interval-for-regression-with-clustered-standard-error-in-ggplot) and amended my code by changing the `geom_smooth` line to this `geom_smooth(method = 'loess', method.args = list(cluster = df$mun_code))`, but it didn't change the actual graph.

How can I make sure the confidence bounds shown on my graph are using clustered SE.

Comment: The best way to make sure the correct standard errors are being shown is to calculate them outside of ggplot (using whatever method is most appropriate) then either merge them into your main dataset or plot them as a separate layer.